# Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo: (500) Backend Error'

Tags: php, oop, google-api

I have setup Google Login for one of my sites (vps hosting - apache). Not a problem at all, pretty much exactly the same as facebook login... easy!

I have another site (shared hosting - apache - addon domain), it doesn't have SSL yet, so i cant implement facebook login. From what i have seen, google is not as fussy about ssl yet. So i planned to do twitter and google+ login for this non ssl site. Atleast until i actually feel its worth moving to the next phase and setting ssl up.

So i literally did exactly the same as before, i have obviously cchanged the relevant parts like the insert sql and the redirects and google dev console. Yet im getting this annoying problem;

The page just continuosely redirects from my site back to google and so on until the browser decided there is a redirect loop. In my server error logs i have this;

```
     [16-Sep-2016 11:40:26 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo: (500) Backend Error' in [sensoredforSO]/GplusLogin/src/io/Google_REST.php:66
Stack trace:
#0 [sensoredforSO]/GplusLogin/src/io/Google_REST.php(36): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#1 [sensoredforSO]/GplusLogin/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(177): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#2 [sensoredforSO]/GplusLogin/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php(37): Google_ServiceResource->__call('get', Array)
#3 [sensoredforSO]/GplusLogin/index.php(30): Google_UserinfoServiceResource->get()
#4 {main}
  thrown in [sensoredforSO]GplusLogin/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 66
```

Google doesnt seem to have any content on this so i thought id throw it out to you boffins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Really simple. Upgrade to the latest version of the google api SDK from Github, Make sure the server is running php 4 or above. Hey presto! it works. So much for this place having boffins!